# Seaborn - plotting an additional moving average line in relplot

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, facet-grid

I would like to get some suggestions on how to plot the moving average line for each of subplots created by the following relplot. I've initially attempted to use sns.lineplot() but I couldn't get what I wanted.

The MA calculation that I'm planning on using is:

```
df['avg_price'].rolling('24H', min_periods=360).mean()
```

So far I attempted to use in `for ax in g.axes.flat` basic plot `ax.plot(df.index, df['avg_price'].rolling('24H', min_periods=360).mean(), color='orange', label='MA', lw=1.5)` or sns.lineplot

Neither of them worked, so I wondering what else I could do?

The code below plots 24 smaller subplots and for each I would like to plot the moving average line.

```
facet_kws={'sharey': False}
g= sns.relplot(
    data=df, x=df.index, y="avg_price", col="customer", 
    kind="line", col_wrap=4, 
    color='k', alpha=0.75, facet_kws=facet_kws,
);
g.set_axis_labels("Date", "Average price", fontsize=13);
g.set_titles("{col_name}", size=14);
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=60, fontsize=13);
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.HourLocator(interval=24))
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.axvspan(pd.Timestamp(start_test), pd.Timestamp(end_test), color='y', alpha=0.25, lw=0);
```

Example of my dataset:
The dataframe looks like this:

```
                    customer    avg_price   avg_price2  count1  count2  
date_time                       
2022-06-11 00:00:00 Customer1   4.4656  1.25    36  11084
2022-06-11 00:00:00 Customer2   7.8873  0.92    10  22150
2022-06-11 00:00:00 Customer3   2.3016  1.37    1   2521
2022-06-11 00:00:00 Customer4   3.2421  1.05    221 98973
2022-06-11 00:00:00 Customer5   1.0050  0.94    2   410
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2022-06-21 10:00:00 Customer1   4.9450  1.99    340 118000  
2022-06-21 10:00:00 Customer2   4.0643  2.06    268 20850   
2022-06-21 10:00:00 Customer3   3.7034  1.00    25  5100    
2022-06-21 10:00:00 Customer4   5.0367  2.64    2098 118251  
2022-06-21 10:00:00 Customer5   2.7429  1.57    50  11900
```

Date_time is the index column, minute based frequency.

Any suggestions/examples?

EDIT: I tried to add the MA to the dataframe itself as a column and succeeded ([Pandas - assign groupby rolling mean results to new column respecting initial dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72714465/pandas-assign-groupby-rolling-mean-results-to-new-column-respecting-initial-da?noredirect=1#comment128439539_72714465)) but then I couldn't find a way to plot this column using seaborn. I found suggestions regarding transforming the format of the data but I'm not quite sure how this would work.

Comment: You have to `.melt` the dataframe into a long form and then separate the lines by using `hue=`. The question is not reproducible without an example of the data.

Comment: I'll edit my post so that it has some example of the data.

Comment: judging how my data looks like after attempting to use `.melt` I probably don't understand how hue is supposed to work if I'm also using `col=` to create for each a smaller plot.